# Laravel: Check if record exists Before Insertion

Tags: php, laravel-5, error-handling

I have two tables: **`assignments`** table(columns `assignment_id`, `Staff Name`, `asset_id`, `department`, `date`, `status`), and an **`assets`** table (columns `asset_id`, `tag_name`, `serial_number`, `model_number`, `color`). The **asset** table columns are linked with the **assignments** table. I want to perform an insertion into the assignments table but before the insertion, i want to check if the **`asset_id`** already exists in the assignments table & if it's **`status`** = 'Active' then the insertion should throw an error/shouldn't happen.

**AssignmentsController**

```
class AssignmentController extends Controller
{

public function assignment(){
    $assignments = Assignment::all();
    return view('assignment/index', ['assignments' => $assignments]);
}   

  public function add(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'assignment_id' => '',
        'staff_name' => 'required',
        'asset_id' => 'required',
        'department' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required'
    ]);
    $assignments =  new Assignment;
    $assignments  ->assignment_id = $request->input('assignment_id');
    $assignments  ->staff_id  = $request->input('staff_id');
    $assignments  ->asset_id = $request->input('asset_id');
    $assignments  ->department_id = $request->input('department_id');
    $assignments  ->date  = $request->input('date');
    $assignments  ->status = $request->input('status');

$count = Assignment::where('status', '=' ,'Active' )->
    where('asset_id', '=' ,$assignments->asset_id)->
    count();
    if($count) {
        abort(405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned asset');
    }

    $assignments  ->save();
    return redirect('/assignment/index') ->with('info', 'New Assignment Saved Successfully!');
}
```

**`Assginment.php`**

```
class Assignment extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'assignment_id';    

    public function asset()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Asset', 'asset_id');
    }
}
```

The below variable and if statement in the **`AssignmentsController`** always throws the error in the **`if statement`** whether it's true or not and the insertion doesn't happen but when the whole statement is cleared, the insertion happens.

```
$count = Assignment::where('status', '=' ,'Active' )->
        where('asset_id', '=' ,$assignments->asset_id)->
        count();
        if($count) {
            abort(405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned asset');
        }
```

So i want a way to check if the the record to be inserted already exists  with conditions as if **`asset_id`** exists then check for it's **`status`** if it's ='Active' then throw an error but if not then insertion happens. Please help if you understand it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It trhow the error even if you don't have the 'status', '=' ,'Active' and 'asset_id', '=' ,$assignments->asset_id ??

Comment: Yeah, it does throw the `abort(405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned asset');` error even if you don't have the 'status', '=' ,'Active' and 'asset_id', '=' ,$assignments->asset_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution**

```
  $count = Assignment::where('asset_id', '=' ,$assignments->asset_id)->
        where('status', '=' ,'Active')->
        count();
        if($count == 1 && $assignments->status != 'Disable') {
            abort(405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned asset');
        }
```

The mistake in my code: I was counting all Assignments and if there is any active status i got an error....I needed to check exactly that assignment which i want to assign which was either active or disable then the assignment should occur or not pertaining it's status(active/disable). Thanks Y'all esp  [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos).

Comment: `if ( Assignment::where('asset_id', '=' ,$assignments->asset_id)->where('status', '=' ,'Active')->exists() ) {
    abort(405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned asset');
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
public function add(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'assignment_id' => '',
        'staff_name' => 'required',
        'asset_id' => 'required',
        'department' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required'
    ]);
    $assignment = Assignment::firstOrNew([ 
           "status" => "Active", 
           "asset_id" => $assignments->asset_id
    ], $request->all()); 
    abort_if($assignment->exists(), 405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned asset'); 
    $assignment->save();
    return redirect('/assignment/index')
          ->with('info', 'New Assignment Saved Successfully!');
}
```

Comment: `$assignment = Assignment::firstOrNew(["status" => "Active",            "asset_id" => $assignments->asset_id], $request-all());
        abort_if($assignment->exists(), 405, 'Trying to assign an already assigned asset');`                                                                                                                                         I get a **FatalErrorException: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\all()**  after editing the add function with the above lines of code your provided. Could you kindly help me rectify to fix this error?

Comment: i don't get what your tryin' to say. how do i get the error fixed?

Comment: okay I've tested it and it works but it's not working the way i intended it to work. It works if the asset_id matches any record in the table with the same asset_id but i want it to meet two conditions. what i wanted it to do is if the record to be inserted matches any record in the table with the same asset_id and it's status as 'Active', do not insert else if the record to be inserted matches any record which has the same asset_id but it's status = 'Disable' or anything apart from 'Active' then insert. Please let me know if you don't get me and kindly help me out if you do, Thanks Again

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. The above code will (or should) find the first `Assignment` which has `status = "Active"` and `asset_id = $assignments->asset_id` and will fail if it finds it.

Comment: it works but it also doesn't allow insertion once the asset_id exists in the table. I just tested it again for confirmation and I'm now getting a **MassAssignmentException** : status. Please check my latest question for clarification to the problem.

Comment: Mass assignment exception can be resolved by adding the appropriate fields in the $fillable array of your model.

Comment: I've updated the $fillable array and i'm getting the error message in the abort function whether the it's a different asset or not. i think what it does is to check in the table if there's any status as 'Active' and belongs an asset then no matter what the insertion may be it will call the abort function. check stackoverflow.com/questions/47743569/… I've updated the question, Please. @apokryfos